# Account created using web3 is not showing in geth console

Tags: web3js, accounts, addresses

I have created a new address using `web3.eth.accounts.create()` and it responds with

```
{ address: '0x9AA2767207d0aC9cCdD2e3B244210f630588F3E3',
  privateKey:
   '0x15bc394db36ab8745ca34a9961d84abf5a45697823726d500785df940e416cbc',
  signTransaction: [Function: signTransaction],
  sign: [Function: sign],
  encrypt: [Function: encrypt] }
```

But in geth console, it lists out all my accounts, except `0x9AA2767207d0aC9cCdD2e3B244210f630588F3E3`. What have gone wrong here? I'm using `web3 -1.0.0-beta.34` . I also tried using `web3.eth.personal.newAccount('qwerty')` but it shows `The method personal_newAccount does not exist/is not available` but clearly they mentioned this method in the 1.0.0 documentation.

I have initialised web3 and personal like

```
var personal = new Personal('http://localhost:8545' || 'ws://localhost:8546');  
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545') || 'ws://localhost:8546');
```

Can some one help me on this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sue you have allowed personal api while starting geth like `geth --rpc --rpcport "8545" --rpcapi personal`

Comment: yes, thank you. Previously I have allowed web3 only.

Answer (score 1):

The method that you use `web3.eth.accounts.create()` creates an account but doesn't link it to your node, instead use `newAccount`:

`web3.eth.personal.newAccount(password, [callback])`

That should do. For further details see the docs [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#newaccount)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried using that also but it shows method doesn't exists

Comment: The method exists!!, look at the docs in the link I provided, what version of web3 are you using.

Comment: web3 -1.0.0-beta.34

Comment: I think initialising personal is the problem. I have initialised like new Personal('http://localhost:8545'  || 'ws://localhost:8546'). Is this correct?